# UIImageView animation: manual frame advance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, nsarray

I am developing an iPhone app with a UIImageView. The UIImageView is populated from an NSArray. What I would like to know, is how to, instead of using the

```
[imageView startAnimating];
```

call, how can I use a UIButton to advance between images?

here is my viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    imageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
                                 nil];
;    imageView.animationDuration = 10.00;
    imageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
    [imageView startAnimating];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];

}
```

Also, I would like to know how to, based on this code, how to when the app starts, have the ImageView on image 1.png?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. `[UIImage animationImages]` is meant for an animation, not a slideshow-type effect. It's meant for your own implementations of `UIActivityIndicator` for instance.

Comment: OK. Thank you. If that will not work, what do you think I should use to create such an effect?

Comment: Make a simple slideshow view that advances the `UIImageView` current image every time the button is pressed.

Comment: That is what I wanted to do, but how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Just keep an array of your `UIImage`s handy and change the `UIImageView`'s image property on each button press.  Something like this perhaps:

```
// ivars
NSUInteger imageIndex;
NSArray *images;

// initialization
images = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
                                 nil] retain];
imagesIndex = 0;
imageView.image = [images objectAtIndex:imagesIndex];
```

and in the button's action method:

```
- (void)someAction:(id)sender {
  imagesIndex = (imagesIndex + 1) % [images count];
  imageView.image = [images objectAtIndex:imagesIndex];
}
```

Comment: `imagesIndex` needs to be an instance variable.

Comment: how would i make images index an instance variable?

Comment: In your interface (.h file), put `@property (monatomic) NSUInteger imagesIndex;`